# Android SQLite unrecognized token

Tags: android, sqlite

Hi I am having trouble with an SQL database, it is giving me an error within my onCreate() method, I am relatively new to both database work and android programming so i'm really quite confused.

Here is my code

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" + KEY_ROWID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_TITLE
                + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_PATH + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + KEY_TAGS + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
    }
```

the error i am getting from logcat is this

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1537): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "'s (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, video_title TEXT NOT NULL, path_in_system TEXT NOT NULL, search_tags TEXT NOT NULL);": , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Video's (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, video_title TEXT NOT NULL, path_in_system TEXT NOT NULL, search_tags TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Comment: try removing the apos from DATABASE_TABLE1 to use Videos instead of Video's

Comment: The database table name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (normally) name a table `Video's`. Maybe you just meant to use `Videos`?

However, if for any reason you absolutely need the table to be named `Video's` (with the apostrophe) or any other non-standard identifier, then you can use either double quotes or brackets. For example, this does work:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE [" + DATABASE_TABLE1 + "] (" + KEY_ROWID ...);
```

as does this:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE \"" + DATABASE_TABLE1 + "\" (" + KEY_ROWID ...);
```